# Receiving Data from NSInputStream in Swift

Tags: swift, inputstream, nsstream

I try to send and receive data with NSOutputStream and NSInputStream in Swift. The sending of data is working well, but i have some questions about the receiving.

I found a solution with handling the NSStreamEvent, which i have tried.

First of all my function for initializing the connection:

```
func initNetworkCommunication(){  
    var host : CFString = "127.0.0.1"
    var port : UInt32 = 7001
    var readstream : Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writestream : Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, port, &readstream, &writestream)

    inputstream = readstream!.takeRetainedValue()
    outputstream = writestream!.takeRetainedValue()

    inputstream.delegate = self
    outputstream.delegate = self


    inputstream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    outputstream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    inputstream.open()
    outputstream.open()   
}
```

This part is working. I have set the delegates to self, so i should be able to handle the NSStreamEvents in this class.

```
func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {
    switch (eventCode){
    case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
        NSLog("Stream opened")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
        NSLog("HasBytesAvailable")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
         NSLog("ErrorOccurred")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
        NSLog("EndEncountered")
        break
    default:
        NSLog("unknown.")
    }
}
```

In my understanding everytime when some data arrives, it should print "HasBytesAvaible", but it printed "unknown." everytime. So i played around a bit and it worked with this:

```
func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {

    var buffer = [UInt8](count: 4096, repeatedValue: 0)
    while (inputstream.hasBytesAvailable){
        let result: Int = inputstream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
    }

    switch (eventCode){
    case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
        NSLog("Stream opened")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
        NSLog("HasBytesAvailable")
        var output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        NSLog("output: %@", output)
        receiveMessage(output) //only adds the message to an array
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
        NSLog("ErrorOccurred")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
          NSLog("EndEncountered")
        break
    default:
        NSLog("unknown.")
    }
}
```

It's working this way, but i wanted to ask you whether this is the right way ? What is the best practice at this point ?

**UPDATE** 
I worked on it again a few weeks ago and figured out my mistakes. So here is the working code.

```
func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {
        switch (eventCode){
    case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
        NSLog("ErrorOccurred")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
        NSLog("EndEncountered")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.None:
        NSLog("None")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
        NSLog("HasBytesAvaible")
        var buffer = [UInt8](count: 4096, repeatedValue: 0)
        if ( aStream == inputstream){

            while (inputstream.hasBytesAvailable){
                var len = inputstream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count) 
                if(len > 0){
                    var output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) 
                    if (output != ""){
                        NSLog("server said: %@", output!)
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.allZeros:
        NSLog("allZeros")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
        NSLog("OpenCompleted")
        break
    case NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable:
        NSLog("HasSpaceAvailable")
        break
  }
```

Comment: Hi, this solution working for multiple response at a time ?

Comment: The above code is for receiving a message, not for responding to it. There are frameworks for sending and responding with sockets, maybe take a look at socket.io http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/

Comment: Yeah, its for receiving message but i want ask you is it going to handle if i got multiple responses from server at same time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the event `hasSpaceAvailable`, which I expect is occurring when it says "unknown". It's telling you that it is ready to receive more data.

Generally, I avoid using `default` in switch statements for enums, since the compiler will tell you when you've missed something.

Comment: I figured it out a few weeks ago. I will accept your answer here, because you're right. This was my mistake.

Comment: Glad you sorted it – I only realised the date of your question after I'd answered!

Comment: @Alexander this solution will work for multiple response at a time ? in (UPDATE)

Comment: @K.Shrikant I think you'll get better answers if you create a new question

Answer (score 3):

I am using the code written by hoedding, and noticed a mistake. The line:

```
var output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

should be replaced by:

```
var output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: len, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

You have to get in the `output` var only the number of characters returned by the server, and not the full length of the buffer, or you will get garbage from previous requests.